# Selecting objects within a class

Tags: css, css-selectors

So, this is a question that's been nagging at me for a long time.  I've been digging much more into CSS these days.  I'm trying to stay away from jQuery for this project as it's in Drupal and I'm trying to stay away from custom code.

So, we have a class the system applies to BODY called "not-logged-in" when the user isn't logged in.  Now this *should* work well for us (as I understand CSS), as we're only allowing admins to "log in".  We are having collisions when we have someone editing a node -- all our custom classes are loaded in both cases and some of the editing controls are looking funky because of it.

So the BODY style is something like this:

```
<body class="html not-front not-logged-in no-sidebars page-node page-node- page-node-1 node-type-page footer-columns" >

    ... [much body content here--other divs, other classes, elements with IDs] ...

    <div class='mycustomclass'>Should be bigger if logged in</div>
</body>
```

So, when I try to add a CSS selector and style, like this:

```
.not-logged-in .mycustomclass {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

It seems to ignore .mycustomclass.  I've run into this before and chalked it up to my poor CSS-fu.  And there was always jQuery, so I really didn't have to care.  I'd really appreciate it if someone could clear this long-time mystery up for me.

Comment: Wow.  I'm marked down with no explanation?  If this is something obvious, my apologies.  If you're going to say this is a bad question, at least tell me *why* you think it's a bad question.

Comment: Personally I think this is a good question. That said, you may wish to elaborate on the collisions you're facing when editing nodes. Are you able to debug these collisions, what do you see when inspecting the page, and so on. If you're able to obtain some more information it may help us find a solution.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle to illustrate your problem? I have tried your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/RNzxd/ and it seems to work for me.

Comment: Can you paste the least code that can demo your problem on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: That should be working, or Mordernizr wouldn't exist. Be sure that your css selector is under the body

Comment: Your current approach should work.  There must be some other piece of code, which you haven't show to us, that is causing your problem.  Can you provide a demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is fine, no problems there.

I imagine one of two problems:

1. The class is not actually being loaded, either on the body, or on your `mycustomclass` element. Check both in the *rendered* source (i.e. in the browser), not just your own code. As it's Drupal, it could be caching so your changes are not being loaded. **Clear the Drupal cache**.
2. Specificity. Perhaps there is another class on the element, or perhaps there's a global rule. Either way, something could be overriding your CSS on that element.

To solve both, use Firebug and the Web Developer Toolbar in Firefox. Both are essential for doing CSS.

Comment: or press `F12` if you are using another browser ;)

Comment: So, this *SHOULD* work and does for everyone else.  That's good to know!  I'll dig further.  Thanks for the help.  And I've been using the Developer tools in Chrome as well as in Safari--so good info.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that Drupal is adding the css script tags in the `<head>` of your HTML. You should have them follow after your stylesheet references. That's it, the drupal css (the one that is adding the not-logged-in class to the `<body>`) must execute before your css.